# How to get data attribute from jQuery tokenize when adding tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [jQuery tokenize](https://www.zellerda.com/projects/tokenize) to select multiple items.In my js code i have dynamically load the items into `select` via a REST call.In there i have add HTML `data attribute (data-tc-dependency)`to my each populated item.

```
items.forEach(function(e, i) {
            var opt = $("<option data-tc-dependency='bird'></option>");
            opt.text(e.key);
            opt.val(e.key);
            opt.attr('html', optionHtml);
            selectTag.append(opt);
        });
```

when i am adding tokens i need to run some logic on it check whether if its a correct data type.in jQuery tokenize API there is a function called `onAddToken`
it fires when adding items.So in there i tried to get the data attribute but i coudnt only i can access is `value` and `text` only.I tried with `this` and it throws me an error.

```
onAddToken: function(value, text, e){
    console.log($(this).data('data-tc-dependency'));
 }
```

please let me know how can i get `data attribute` from jQuery tokenize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have noted a mistake in your question. When you are using .data(), you can remove the data and use the rest.
>
> **Eg:** In your question you can use `.data('tc-dependency')` **not** `.data('data-tc-dependency')`

Since you are having access to the value, you can select the option with the corresponding value like

```
$('select option[value="'+value+'"]')
```

Your code for getting the data attribute will look like the code given below

```
$('select option[value="'+value+'"]').data('tc-dependency')
```

**DEMO**

```js
console.log($('select option[value="volvo"]').data('tc-dependency'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" data-tc-dependency='bird'>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @gihan Glad to here that. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the attr function, like this :

```
  onAddToken: function(value, text, e){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-tc-dependency'));
  }
```